# AWS Lambda : module initialization error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I create a Lambda function on AWS with library call [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) to check the mimeType from uploaded S3 file event. Everything works fine on my machine with mock test event. I'm sure that I upload all the dependency inside `node_modules` to Lambda.

**This is an error message from Lambda  :**

```
module initialization error: Error
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/var/task/node_modules/mmmagic/lib/index.js:3:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

**Here is my code :**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const mmagic = require('mmmagic');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key
    }
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack) // an error occurred
        else {
            var magic = new mmagic.Magic();
            magic.detect(data.Body, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error when try getting mime type:' + err) // logherer
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

}

**package.json**

```
{
    "aws-sdk": "^2.188.0",
    "mmmagic": "^0.4.6"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to Node.js version you use and Node.js version that is on Lambda.
As you can on their [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/aws-lambda-supports-node-js-6-10/) the latest version that lambda supports is `6.10`

So, the solution for your problem is to

- downgrade the version of Node.js to `6.10.0`. Use, for example [nvm](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)
- remove your `node_modules/`
- install all modules with `npm i` again

And only then try to upload your zip to Lambda.

Comment: How can you tell?  I am no expert at reading Node.js stack traces, but I don't see anything particularly useful in the stack trace.  Which information in the original question helps you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @Natsathorn Was it useful for you?

Comment: @YevheniiHerasymchuk I would not try yet, I will ping you when i try.

Comment: @Natsathorn was it actually solved? 
Maybe you can describe more about the details